# Use Python Github Repository in Google Colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to clone a Github Repository in Colab and run it. The problem is that Colab says that it couldn't import tqdm.contrib, even if tqdm is contained in Colab.

```
import os

!git clone https://github.com/scorpion3013/checkolotl
os.chdir("checkolotl/")
!python3 main.py
```

main.py calls other .py files and it completely works on my PC.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import checkolotl.proxy as proxychecker
  File "/content/checkolotl/checkolotl/proxy.py", line 3, in <module>
    from checkolotl.status import create_bar
  File "/content/checkolotl/checkolotl/status.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tqdm.contrib import DummyTqdmFile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm.contrib'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tqdm](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/#faq-and-known-issues) (progress bars) has its own limitations.
In another project ([`keras-team/autokeras`](https://github.com/keras-team/autokeras)), tqdm was not working either ([issue 307](https://github.com/keras-team/autokeras/issues/307)) on Google Colab due to the lack of ipywidgets.

[This was the PR](https://github.com/keras-team/autokeras/pull/343) done in that other project to resolve the issue.
Maybe it can be adapted here.